# Light Attenuation in Raytracer

Tags: java, raytracing, light

I'm writing a ray tracer, but I'm having some trouble with how light is supposed to drop off with distance to the light source.
It seems like the values for distances are just too high, so when I square them and divide the intensity by them I end up with just a black screen.
How would I change the the instensity of a light source on a pixel without it overpowering the scene. Right now my code is

```
    finalColour.r += (diffuseColour.r * light.intensity.r * x /(distance*distance));
    finalColour.g += (diffuseColour.g * light.intensity.g * x /(distance*distance));
    finalColour.b += (diffuseColour.b * light.intensity.b * x /(distance*distance));
```

Answer (score 2):

what is x?  the math looks correct.  are you sure it is not a problem with the configuration of the scene: make the light intensity / diffuseColour higher, or the distances smaller.  alternatively, while light drop off as the square of the distance is physicaly acurate, you do not need to use it in your raytracer.  you could use the unsquared distance for a less realistic but brighter scene.

Comment: x is the Lambertian Coefficient. The Problem I think is that r g b and x are all in the range of 0 - 1 while the distance is the actual distance so would be in the 100 to 1000 range.

Comment: You likely need to make `light.intensity` bigger